# C# passing decimal value to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, decimal

I'm working SQL Server database. Table column decimal(13,2) I send value from c# decimal type parameter.My problem's when send value 400.00 from c# but value saved 40000.00.Can you help me please?

```
 decimal amount = Convert.ToDecimal(txttutar.Text,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

 SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@AMOUNT", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = amount;
```

Comment: Please share your C# code

Comment: I add my  c# code

Comment: What does `amount=?` ?

Comment: You are using InvariantCulture to convert your text in decimal. Are you sure about this? Does your textbox contain a text with a point as decimal separator?

Answer (score 6):

The symptoms you describe are a clear sign that your input doesn't match the InvariantCulture settings.

If your culture uses, as separator for decimal values, a comma or something else but a point, then converting a text using InvariantCulture could produce a wrong value.

For example, in my culture (it-IT) converting *400,00* (a correct decimal in it-IT) with InvariantCulture results in the mentioned value of *40000*.
Use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture instead

```
decimal amount = Convert.ToDecimal(txttutar.Text,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Said that, do not use Convert.ToDecimal to convert user input.
If the user types something that is not a valid decimal number (leaves the input blank or types a string like "ABC") the Convert.ToDecimal will throw an exception.
Instead use decimal.TryParse and check the output

```
decimal amount;
if(!decimal.TryParse(txttutar.Text, NumberStyles.None, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out amount))
    // Message for your user -- Invalid number --
else
    // go on with the database code....
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```
decimal amount = Convert.ToDecimal(txttutar.Text,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

SqlParameter amtParam = new SqlParameter("@AMOUNT", SqlDbType.Decimal);

amtParam.Precision = 13;
amtParam.Scale = 2;
amtParam.Value = amount;

SqlCmd.Parameters.Add(amtParam);
```